# Evaluating $\frac{\cos 10^\circ \cos 50^\circ\cos 70^\circ}{\cos 30^\circ}$

Tags: trigonometry

$$\frac{\cos 10^\circ \cos 50^\circ\cos 70^\circ}{\cos 30^\circ} = ?$$
I use double sine formula $$\sin2A=2\sin A \cos A$$
But isn't help to reduce any fraction but more degree of $\sin 40^\circ$

How should I do after that?

Comment: How is the sine rule going to help when your expression has no $\sin$ in it~?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\frac{\cos10^{\circ}\cos50^{\circ}\cos70^{\circ}}{\cos30^{\circ}}=\frac{(\cos60^{\circ}+\cos40^{\circ})\cos70^{\circ}}{2\cos30^{\circ}}=$$
$$=\frac{\cos10^{\circ}+\cos130^{\circ}+\cos110^{\circ}+\cos30^{\circ}}{4\cos30^{\circ}}=$$
$$=\frac{\cos10^{\circ}+2\cos120^{\circ}\cos10^{\circ}}{4\cos30^{\circ}}+\frac{1}{4}=\frac{1}{4}.$$

Answer (score 1):

**Hints:**

The result is 1/4.

$$
\frac{\cos(10°)\cos(50°)\cos(70°)}{\cos(30°)} = \frac{\sin(80°)\sin(40°)\sin(20°)}{\sin(60°)} 
$$

You might have to use trigonometric arc tri-section.

Good luck.